# Using jQuery scroll function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add a class `.red` to `#box-1` on scroll down using following code at [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/ytQtAZYDmT).

```
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 30) {
        $("#box-1").addClass("red");

    } else {
        $("#box-1").removeClass("red");

    }
});
```

the HTML:

```
<div id="box-1" class="row"></div>
<div id="box-2" class="row"></div>
<div id="box-3" class="row"></div>
```

and CSS:

```
.red{ background-color: red;  }
#box-1{background-color: yellow;   height:300px; width:100px;}
#box-2{background-color: green;   height:300px; width:100px;}
#box-3{background-color: blue;   height:300px; width:100px;}
```

But it is not working! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add !important > .red{ background-color: red !important;  }

Comment: use !important; is bad practice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `!important` to the `background-color` of the red class does the trick.

ids identify elements. classes classify elements. ids have higher specificity and so 
their styles have higher precedence.

```
.red{ background-color: red !important; }
```

See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2v9fn1np/1/

Using `!important` is bad practice and usually an indicator that you have not utilized classes and ids effectively. In this case, to add the style, you can edit the style attribute of the element directly and achieve the highest precedence. Use jQuery's `css` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't noticed, the is getting the CLASS "red". 
The problem is that you've referred to it's ID has having a yellow background. And since the ID is predominante over a CLASS, you must add it to the CLASS, EX:

```
#box-1.red{ background-color: red; }
```